# How can i pass or keep my cheched checkbox when the page is changed in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a gridview it includes checkboxes. When i click them it goes to SelectedRss_Click function and I can keep the data thanks to it. However, when i change tha page of gridview, the checked checkboxes are unchecked. How can i solve this problem.

My SelectedRss_Click function.

```
protected void SelectedRss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList listcategory = new ArrayList();
    list.Clear();
    listcategory.Clear();                
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("FeedSelector");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            string feedURL = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
            string rsscategory = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
            list.Add(feedURL);
            listcategory.Add(rsscategory);
            Session["SelectedFeedURL"] = list;
            Session["SelectedFeedCategory"] = listcategory;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can do disposing page and where ?

Comment: @Pankaj Garg's answer is a good one. You could alternativly make the pages definition global in the calling class, this would persist the page and it contents for reuse...

Answer (score 1):

**[ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)**

It's because by end of the [**Page Life Cycle**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic2) all controls get `Disposed` and `State of the Page` will be lost.

- **Preventive Action**

  While changing the page of `GridView`, in the `PageindexChanging` event of `GridView`, 
  save checked checkboxes row details of the Current Page in `ViewState`. Similarly you 
  can remove the rows from `ViewState` from unchecked GridView `CheckBox` rows.
- **Corrective Action**

  The saved records in `ViewState` will be checked in GridView on `PageIndexChanging` Event.

Comment: I tried to copy my codes in pageindexchanging but how can i do it saving the gridview state.

Comment: I did it by copying the codes which are above. is there any else method. saving records.